# Page doesn't load if i dont manually put .php

Tags: php, apache

I am a newbie, and i am having issues with this website. Please help.

So when ever i try to access links on my website it gives me a "Not Found" error. You can see for your self https://classified.machela.org/post-ad

But if i am to out https://classified.machela.org/post-ad.php the page will load.

Do you know what could be the issue ?

Comment: Yes. The page is loaded by a script called `post-ad.php` not a script called `post-ad` So unless you have something like rewrite working to add the `.php` apache cannot find the resource as it does not exist

Comment: You'll need to configure .htaccess file.

Comment: I am now getting 500 error

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any CMS you can add this in your .httacces file in root directory of your website (if you use Apache)

```
    RewriteEngine on 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Can you share access to the server?

Comment: You can create info PHP file and check is it modrewrite enabled.